# Can this recursive binary search in C be made more concise?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search, reinventing-the-wheel

Can someone please let me know if they see glaring issues with this code? I tested a handful of cases and it seems to work but in other threads.  I often see much more concisely written versions of this.  I just want to know if anything I have done is superfluous or just stylistically poor form.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int value = 5;
int values[] = {2,4,5,12,23,34};
int n = 6;

int re_search(int value, int values[], int n);

int main(void)
{

    re_search(value, values, n);
    return 0; 
} 

int re_search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = n-1;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last)
    {
        if (value == values[middle])
        {
            printf("Found it!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (value > values[middle])
        {
          first = middle + 1;
          middle = (first + last) / 2;
          return re_search(value, &values[middle], last-first);
        }    
        else
        {
            last = middle - 1;
            return re_search(value, &values[middle], last-first);
        }    
        middle = (first + last) / 2;

    }
    printf("Did not find it\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As @syb0rg noted, you have a stray `if(value <0)` that causes compilation to fail. Furthermore, if you try with `int value = 34` instead of 5, it won't find it.

Comment: There is a standard library function [`bsearch()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/) that can accomplish this same task, so I am tagging this with "reinventing-the-wheel".

Comment: @200_success thanks for catching this. I now see it will not find the value if it is either the first or last in the array.  Now just need to figure out why. Probably something to do with how I calculate middle.  I thought this would recursively shorten the array such that every number would eventually be a "middle" to be compared to the value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Things you did well

- Declaring your parameters as `void` when you don't take in any arguments.
- Keeping your dependencies to a minimum.

## Things you could improve

#### Bugs:

- You sorted your array for your program.

  > ```
  > int values[] = {2,4,5,12,23,34};
  > ```

  Your program fails to find your `value` if your array is not sorted initially.

  ```
  int values[] = {9,4,3,12,69,34};
  ```

  Let the computer do the hard work by using [`qsort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

#### Efficiency:

- Recursion is slowing you down in your `re_search()` method.  Use iteration instead.  The conversion isn't too hard, there are a lot of similarities.

  ```
  int binarySearch(int a[], int low, int high, int target)
  {
      while (low <= high)
      {
          int middle = low + (high - low)/2;
          if (target < a[middle]) high = middle - 1;
          else if (target > a[middle]) low = middle + 1;
          else return middle;
      }
      return -1;
  }
  ```

#### Variables/Initialization:

- You shouldn't use global variables.

  > ```
  > int value = 5;
  > int values[] = {2,4,5,12,23,34};
  > int n = 6;
  > ```

  The problem with global variables is that since every function has access to these, it becomes increasingly hard to figure out which functions actually read and write these variables.

  To understand how the application works, you pretty much have to take into account every function which modifies the global state. That can be done, but as the application grows it will get harder to the point of being virtually impossible (or at least a complete waste of time).

  If you don't rely on global variables, you can pass state around between different functions as needed. That way you stand a much better chance of understanding what each function does, as you don't need to take the global state into account.

  So instead of using global variables, initialize the variables in `main()`, and pass them as arguments to functions if necessary.
- Right now your `n` variable is hard coded.

  > ```
  > int n = 6;
  > ```

  Since this is just the number of elements in your array, we can make this a bit more dynamic, so that you don't have to change it if you add a few more elements to your array.

  ```
  int n = sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]);
  ```
- Right now you are hard coding the number you are looking for.

  > ```
  > int value = 5;
  > ```

  I would either let the user enter it, or determine a random number to search for.

  ```
  srand((unsigned int) time(NULL)); // seeding
  int val = values[rand() % n];
  ```

#### Syntax/Styling:

- You print out items to the console within your `re_search()` method.

  > ```
  > printf("Found it!\n");
  > ...
  > printf("Did not find it\n");
  > ```

  I would have it so your function only evaluates if the number exists in the array and returns whether it could find it or not.  Then let `main()` do all the printing to the console based on that information.

  ```
  printf("%s\n", (re_search(value, values, n)) ? "Found it!" : "Didn't find it.");
  ```

## Final Code

I've rewritten your code so that it is bug free, and so that it is a bit more dynamic.  I also rewrote some bits so you could see what was going on, and so the program was more transparent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int binarySearch(int a[], int low, int high, int target)
{
    while (low <= high)
    {
        int middle = low + (high - low)/2;
        if (target < a[middle]) high = middle - 1;
        else if (target > a[middle]) low = middle + 1;
        else return middle;
    }
    return -1;
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    printf("{ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    puts("}");
}

int main(void)
{
    int values[] = {16, 7, 5, 94, 24, 34};
    int n = sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]); // find the number of elements in the array
    qsort(values, n, sizeof(values[0]), compare);
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL)); // seeding
    int val = values[rand() % n]; // fetch a random value in the array
    int found = binarySearch(values, 0, n - 1, val);

    printArray(values, n); // just so we can see the sorted array
    if (found >= 0) printf("Found %d at index %d\n", val, found);
    else printf("Didn't find %d\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions. Your code is so much cleaner.  Passing in 0 and n-1 seems like the more optimal approach vs. setting variables in the function and passing in the length.

Comment: @syb0rg: For [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44171/33366), why did you make the "(n^2)" into a subscript? (I'm not talking about just making the "^2" into a superscript.)

Comment: @RickyDemer That is more of a discussion for the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).  I'll talk more about it there.

Comment: The input array being already sorted is usually considered a precondition for binary search. For example, [Java's `binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch\(int[],%20int\)) says that if the array is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution combines iteration and recursion, which means that a lot of unnecessary work is done. Normally you'll want to choose only one method.

A simple iterative version:

```
int re_search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = n-1;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    for(;first <= last;middle = (first + last) / 2)
    {
        if (value == values[middle])
        {
            printf("Found it!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (value > values[middle])
        {
            first = middle + 1;
        }    
        else
        {
            last = middle - 1;
        }    
    }
    printf("Did not find it\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I don't need the while loop

Comment: I've replaced the `while` loop with an equivalent `for` loop - that's mostly a matter of taste. The major change is that the function is no longer recursive.

Comment: @opd You've been pretty active for a new user.  Feel free to join us in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime.